# If two parametrization have the same endpoints, do they have the same path integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $c(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$, for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$, and let $p(t)=(\cos t,−\sin t)$, for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. Is it true that $\displaystyle \int \limits _c​f\,ds=\int \limits _p f\,ds$ for every continuous (real-valued) function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$?
Answer choices are:

a. True for all functions $f$.

b. True for some functions $f$ and false for others.

c. False for all functions $f$.

d. It's complicated.

I tried plugging in the endpoint and see that $c(0)=(1,0)$, $c(2\pi )=(1,0)$, $p(0)=(1,0)$, $p(2\pi )=(1,0)$. Is this sufficient to say it's true for all functions $f$?
Again, thanks and happy math doing!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.

Comment: thank you so much for editting it!!! I'll make sure to latex it next time. :D

Comment: It's not enough that the endpoints be the same; the *paths* have to be the same.  (But in this case, the paths *are* the same, so the integrals are the same, too. I'll elaborate on this in my answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the integrals are the same, but not for the reason you provide.

An integral of the form $\int_C f \, ds$ can be interpreted as representing the signed area of a ``ribbon'' with height $f$ over a base curve $C$, as shown in the image below.  (In the image, the curve $C$ is shown in red in the $xy$-plane.)

[image]

(Parenthetical note: I say that $\int_C f \, ds$ is the **signed area** of the ribbon because, just as in single-variable calculus, we count the area as negative where the function $f$ is negative.  That doesn't affect the considerations here, but is important for understanding the full situation.)

When it's described this way, it should be clear that the area depends only on two things:  the *path*, and the *height function*.  Using two different parametrizations *of the same path* shouldn't make a difference -- it's still the same ribbon!

To return to the example in your question:  $c(t)$ and $p(t)$ are two different parametrizations of the unit circle (one oriented clockwise, one oriented counter-clockwise), so the integrals $\int_c f \, ds$ and $\int_p f \, ds$ are descriptions of the exact same area.

But note that it's **not enough** to verify that the two paths have the same endpoints!  Consider the image below, which shows two different paths joining the two endpoints $A = (1,1)$ and $B = (-1,-11)$. The first path (in red) is a line segment; the second path (in blue) is a semicircle.  Over each paths we construct a ``ribbon'' using the same height function (in this example, $f(x,y) = 2 + x^2 y$). As the image suggests, the ribbons have quite different areas, despite the fact that the paths begin and end at the same point.

[image]

Perhaps the most basic example of this is when we consider the function $f(x,y) = 1$.  Then $\int_c f \, ds$ is the length of the path $c$, and $\int_p f \, ds$ is the length of the path $p$.  Just because two paths begin and end at the same point doesn't automatically mean that they have the same length!  However, if the paths are the same, the integrals will be the same.

(You may find it helpful to think of two different parametrizations of a path as being like two different cars driving down the same road but at different speeds.  The length of the road is the same, regardless of how quickly you drive along it.)

Comment: thank you so much!!!!! I totally get it now!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is true for all f. Because

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(cost,-sint)dt=-\int_{0}^{-2\pi}f(cosu,sinu)du=\int_{-2\pi}^{0}f(cosu,sinu)du=\int_{-2\pi}^{0}f(cos(u+2\pi),sin(u+2\pi))du=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(cost,sint)dt$

Comment: This makes no sense.  $f$ is supposed to be a scalar-valued function, not a vector-valued function.

Comment: OK read my edit ! My new answer! Is even simpler now!

Comment: $\sqrt{1-\cos^2(t)}=|\sin(t)|$

Comment: I changed my answer! I think it is true for all $f$!

Comment: It is very disappointing to give a two line crystal clear proof of the result and get no upvotes but downvotes. Probably some people like complication and not simplicity!

Comment: The downvotes are left over from your initial answer (which was wrong) and your revision (which was also wrong). And while your second revision does address the specific example in the OP, it does not address the general case (as asked in the question title).

Comment: You confused me sir with the revisions! What is wrong with my present answer? Why it does not address the "general case". It is a common (and correct) attitude that when someone deletes or revises his incorrect answer people withdraw the downvote! My present answer is correct, complete and general! You can downvote it too! I have NEVER downvoted anyone's answer these two months I am on the site! I consider it as bad scientific behavior. If I see something wrong I make a comment! If I see something clever I upvote! People who insist  downvoting, time after time, may need some help!